# Live embedded updates for social networks (Facebook, Twitter, Instagram etc.)

Tags: facebook, plugins, twitter, social-networking, expressionengine

Is it possible, ideally with a single plugin, to have any posts made to a number of different social networks displayed on a website in real time?

I plan to have small sections for each feed, which may also be refreshed automatically every minute or so to show the last five entries, but I'd also like to have any updates displayed as popup boxes from social icons in the footer.

Please suggest any plugins that might provide this functionality. They would of course have to have compatibility with the Twitter 1.1 API.

Bear in mind also that the site will eventually be running on ExpressionEngine, so if there are any addons that might integrate better with that CMS, by all means let me know.

Comment: Do you need one widget that pulls in content for many social networks or can you get away with a separate widget for each?

Comment: @AllInOne We're still discussing the best way to implement it, but individual plugins should be fine as long as they can be sufficiently styled to look similar.

Comment: Isn't it enough to embed a Facebook and Twitter plugin? Then for Instagram you either do each manually, or you a widget. There are many, like snapwigdet.com | only problem is, clicking on images redirects to horribly designed site.

Comment: @DaniSpringer I appreciate it, but check the date. I don't even remember what project this was for.

Comment: If it helped please mark up. Ty